# MySQL DATE_ADD usage, 5 day interval

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

I'm trying to select the order total sum ($) and invoice count over a 5 day period in a single query.  I can't seem to get this to happen though.  The current query I have is here...

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) as invoice_count,
    SUM(orderTotal) as orders_sum,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) as created
FROM ids_invoice
WHERE DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL +1 DAY)
AND userId = 23 LIMIT 5'
```

I'm not entirely sure DATE_ADD is the right function I'm looking for.

Currently I'm getting....

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [invoice_count] => 420
        [orders_total] => 97902.90
        [created] => 1252596560
    )
)

Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [invoice_count] => 68
        [orders_total] => 14193.20
        [created] => 1262900809
    )
)
```

I'd like to get something more like...

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [invoice_count] => 18
        [orders_total] => 4902.90
        [date] => 04-19-2010
    )
)

Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [invoice_count] => 12
        [orders_total] => 5193.20
        [date] => 04-20-2010
    )
)
```

I'm fairly new to mysql date functions so perhaps I just missed the function I needed when going through mysql docs.

**UPDATE**
I've updated my query... This still does not pull a row for each day that there were invoices for.  It's only pulling invoices from the 19th when there are invoices from the 20th that meet the userId criteria.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) as invoice_count,
    SUM(orderTotal) as orders_sum,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) as created
FROM ids_invoice
WHERE
    created BETWEEN "2010-04-19 00:00:00" AND DATE_ADD("2010-04-19 00:00:00", INTERVAL +5 DAY) AND
    userId = 17
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get records between a date span, use:

```
WHERE created BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

This example will get you records (assuming any exist for today, including time) for between today and  days into the future.  Look at DATE_SUB if you want to go into the past.

Comment: Is it possible for me to get default values for any figures that don't exist within the specified timeframe?

Comment: @Webnet: You need a list of dates spanning the range you want, to LEFT JOIN onto the `IDS_INVOICE` table based on the date and the `created` value.  MySQL doesn't have recursive subquerying - you can create a numbers table, or use a CROSS JOIN setup to get the date calculation you need.

Comment: I understand the logic of what you're saying, it makes perfect sense.  You're saying I need to `SELECT COUNT(id) as invoice_count FROM ids_invoice LEFT JOIN ids_invoice WHERE created BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)`

I'm sure it's obvious.... but I'm not sure the syntax of what you're talking about.

Comment: Having slept on it, I think I have a better understanding of what you're talking about and realize how wrong the query above is... I spent some more time on Google and failed to find an example of what you're talking about...

Answer (score 2):

If your created column type is int then just try this one

```
created<= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 5 DAY))')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE created <= NOW() AND created >=NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

or it would be better to compare just DATE part of datetime:

```
WHERE DATE(created) <= date(NOW()) AND 
  DATE(created) >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```