# Show records from now() till next 7 days in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to select rows from the datetime now till 7 days in the future, how can I do this?
Read alot about the date function of mysql but cant figure it out, this is the MySQL code:

```
SELECT  id, date_format(datum, '%d/%m') AS date,
        date_format(datum, '%H:%i') AS time, date  
FROM wedstrijden
WHERE date >= now()
ORDER BY datum asc
```

I have to do something with:

```
date >= now() till 7 days further
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684520/mysql-date-add-usage-5-day-interval

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I would submit that the most elegant way would be:

```
WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Edit: [this doc page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) is like the most useful thing ever.  Bookmark it, because it is totally handy.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [INTERVAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) modifier to add a week to the current time as follows:

```
...WHERE date >= NOW() AND date <= NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

Comment: This is the right answer with Tehshrike method I receive mysql_error because it is not 
BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAYS)

but 
BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
days =day

Answer (score 2):

I am also posting the query which worked for me

`where matchdate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)`
This worked if above example doesn't work then try this.

Answer (score 1):

What i use to get all the data from 7 days back till now from the database:

`SELECT * FROM wedstrijden WHERE DATE(date_from_table) > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
"...WHERE date >= NOW() AND date <= ADDTIME(NOW(), 168:00:00)..."
```

should accomplish what you're looking for.  The 168:00:00 is a bit specific for your needs, ADDTIME takes any datetime format.