# MySQL Query - Records between 15 days ago End_date to till End_date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to return records from database 15 days old from `end _date` to till `end_date`! 
I am searching for the query for last 3 days! 
However. I want your help to do a query. Its simple but I'm not sure how to do it.  
I wrote query something like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM bid_post
WHERE ending_date
BETWEEN DATE_SUB( DATE(`ending_date`) , INTERVAL 15 
DAY ) 
AND ending_date >= CURDATE()
```

But it is not working ! 
The data column is a Varchar type. I am storing date as `YYYY-mm-dd` format

Does somebody now how can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: First you need to change your data type to DATE type

Comment: `I want your help to do a query` ? **But what you have tried so far ?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684520/mysql-date-add-usage-5-day-interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this query

```
SELECT *
FROM bid_post
WHERE ending_date between DATE_SUB( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 15 DAY )
AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never store dates as varchar since these are not real dates and you need to store them using mysql native date data types.
Since the format is Y-m-d you may not need to do a conversion using `str_to_date` function and can use the query as

```
select * from bid_post 
where
ending_date between date_sub(curdate(),interval 5 day)  and curdate()
```

This will give you data from last 15 days till today.

Using conversion to real date you need `str_to_date` as

```
select * from bid_post 
where
str_to_date(ending_date,'%Y-%m-%d') between date_sub(curdate(),interval 5 day)  and curdate() ;
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12c4b/3)**